# How can I detect when the Windows desktop is visible?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, windows-10

I have an application that detects if a smartcard is present.  If one is present, it provides video and audio notification to remind the user to remove the smartcard.  Since the smartcard also serves as the key to our buildings, it saves many people from being locked out.

We use Task Scheduler to run it 15 sec after login and unlock.
Unfortunately login can take longer than 15 sec, so sometimes the audio notification occurs before the desktop is visible.

I want to delay the audio notification until after the desktop is visible. So, how can I detect when the Windows desktop is visible?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no notification when a desktop becomes visible. But you can use [`OpenInputDesktop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684309.aspx) and [`GetUserObjectInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683238.aspx) to poll the current desktop periodically until the desired desktop is detected.

Comment: Imagine that you get an advice how to start the show (audio and video) right when the desktop window is created during the startup. I bet that what many common users get will be some slow motion picture with audio playing in forward because their system will be starting many services etc. Desktop window, if that's what you want to detect for creation is one of the first things Windows create when creating session. So I would actually consider what you want to detect.

Comment: @Victoria the visual indication is not video,  It is just a small form in the lower right corner of the screen with its background color changing between red and yellow every 0.5 sec.

Comment: Wait let me get this straight. You are nagging your users if they have their smart card plugged in when they are logged in to computer? Are you serious! If I was one of your employers I would go nuts. Why? Because you often need more than 15 second for smart card being plugged in to use it for let's say digitally signing a document. Also why having to plug in smart card back in every time I would need it and then pull it out just after that is just plain stupid.

Comment: If you want your users not to keep forgetting their smart cards in their computers perhaps it would be better to enable windows `SmarrtCard log-in` feature so that your employee log into their computer with smart card and teach them that they should log out or at least lock out the computer whenever they go away from it. And that can easily be done by simply pulling the smart card out in such case.

Comment: Calm down Silver... nobody is asking you to subject yourselves to the OP's working environment.  In any event, the better solution to smart card access resulting in people being locked out (I suspect they are already using smart card log-in) is to also require the smart card for **egress**.  If you can't leave the building without your smart card then there is a far smaller chance that you'll somehow find yourself outside the building without the card required to get back in.  No ?  But I suspect that would require a bigger change than a simple "nag screen" or reminder on the desktop.

Comment: @SilverWarior yes it is a nag.  People were getting locked out of buildings because their smart card was in the reader.  It only runs after login and unlock and is easily cancelled.  While it may sound stupid to you, it has been responsible for the most complements our IT department has received in the last several years.

Comment: @Deltics Your solution has one problem. It doesn't stop multiple people from leaving one after another while first person unlocks the doors and all others go out through that door before it closes and locks up.

Comment: @Silver - if an idiot wants to ignore the fact that they are *knowingly* leaving the building without their card, then you can't physically stop them.  But if the point is to **remind** someone to take their card with them, then the fact that they *have* to tailgate to get out without their card is about the best reminder you can provide.  And often when there is such access control in place, there will be a site policy that prohibits tailgating, with a corresponding policy to prevent it (it takes two to tailgate) and report if/when observed.  Crowd-Sourced enforcement, if you will.